# Spring batch with couchbase

Tags: spring-batch, couchbase

I have requirement of reading millions of data from couhbase and process it, I want to create spring bootproject with spring batch, but there is no direct support provided in spring batch as CouchbaseItemReader, can any one help if  they have implemented it and how they have used it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official support for Couchbase in Spring Batch. However, there is an open [contribution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/pull/5) by the community in the spring-batch-extensions repository which you can try. This extension is not released.

Comment: This is outdated code , doesn't work with latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Using the reactive kv api is the fastest way to access millions of documents.